# Logging to a file on a Docker volume

Tags: java, docker, logging

I need my Java application to be able to write log to a file on a Docker volume.

I expect the `app.log` file to appear in logs folder, but it doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

My application-related entry in `docker-compose.yaml` is as follows:

```yaml
app:
  build: ./
  container_name: java-app
  ports:
  - 8080:8080
  links:
  - postgresq
  environment:
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://java-postgres:5432/apartments
  depends_on:
    postgresq: 
      condition: service_healthy
  volumes:
    - "./logs/:/app/logs/"
```

My app's `application.properties` contains:

```ini
logging.file.path=/app/logs
logging.file.name=app.log
```

To write log i use something like following:

```java
      ....
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyAppController.class);
      .....
logger.info("Reading");
      .....
```